# Adding data via database inspector shows cannot access offline database

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am trying to add data to m room database via the app inspector in android studio but whenever I launch my app this is what I see, queries get executed successfully but whenever I launch my apps my database items which I present in the form of a lazy column arent displayed

Tried adding data to my database via the database inspector gets added but does not show up in app with cannot access offline database error

Entity:

```
package com.example.taskmaster.data.models

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.example.taskmaster.utils.Constants.Database_Table

@Entity(tableName = Database_Table)
data class Tasks(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int=0,
    val title: String,
    val description:String,
    val priority:Priority
)
```

Database:

```
package com.example.taskmaster.data

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.taskmaster.data.models.Tasks

@Database(entities = [Tasks::class],version=1)
abstract class TaskmasterDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun tasksDao(): TasksDao
}
```

Dao:

```
package com.example.taskmaster.data

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import com.example.taskmaster.data.models.Tasks
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface TasksDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun GetAllTasks(): Flow<List<Tasks>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks_Table WHERE id=:tid")
    fun GetSelectedTask(tid:Int):Flow<Tasks>


    @Insert(onConflict=OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun AddTask(task: Tasks)

    @Delete
    suspend fun DeleteTask(task: Tasks)

    @Update
    suspend fun UpdateTask(task: Tasks)

    @Query("DELETE FROM Tasks_Table")
    suspend fun DeleteAllTasks()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks_Table WHERE title like :searchQuery OR description like :searchQuery")
    fun searchDatabase(searchQuery:String): Flow<List<Tasks>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks_Table ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority LIKE 'L%' THEN 1 WHEN priority like 'M%' THEN 2 WHEN priority LIKE 'H%' THEN 3 END")
    fun sortTasksLow():Flow<List<Tasks>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks_Table ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority LIKE 'H%' THEN 1 WHEN priority like 'M%' THEN 2 WHEN priority LIKE 'L%' THEN 3 END")
    fun sortTasksHigh():Flow<List<Tasks>>


}
```

ViewModel:

```
package com.example.taskmaster.ui.viewmodels

import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.taskmaster.data.models.Tasks
import com.example.taskmaster.data.repositories.TaskmasterRepository
import com.example.taskmaster.utils.RequestState
import com.example.taskmaster.utils.SearchAppBarState
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository:TaskmasterRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val searchAppBarState: MutableState<SearchAppBarState> = mutableStateOf(SearchAppBarState.CLOSED)

    val searchTextState:MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")

    private val _alltasks: MutableStateFlow<RequestState<List<Tasks>>> = MutableStateFlow(RequestState.Idle)

    val alltasks: StateFlow<RequestState<List<Tasks>>> = _alltasks

    fun getalltasks(){
            _alltasks.value=RequestState.Loading
        try{
            viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getAllTasks.collect {
                _alltasks.value = RequestState.Success(it)
            }
            }
            }
        catch(e:Exception){
            _alltasks.value=RequestState.Error(e)
        }
        }
    }
```

Images to help:
[As soon as app launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L5QS.png)
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJarL.png)

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database?utm_source=android-studio#keep-dbs-open

Comment: yes i did it shows the same error